# Python apply function on multiple numbered columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, apply

Here I have an example Datarame.

```
A={'a_1':[1,2,3,4,5],'a_2':[6,7,8,9,4],'a_3':[0,6,2,4,7],'a_4':[3,5,2,4,6],
   'b_1':[1,2,6,4,3],'b_2':[6,7,3,2,4],'b_3':[0,7,2,4,7],'b_4':[3,3,2,4,8]
   }

data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(A)
```

output:

```
a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 b_1 b_2 b_3 b_4
1   6   0   3   1   6   0   3
2   7   6   5   2   7   7   3
3   8   2   2   6   3   2   2
4   9   4   4   4   2   4   4
5   4   7   6   3   4   7   8
```

What I want to do is to compare the difference of columns start with **a** and columns start with **b** with **0**.

like

```
max(data[a_]- data[b_], 0)
```

Does anyone know how could I apply such a function on the dataframe?

What I have tried is something like

```
def test_(row,column_1,column_2):
    result=max(row[column_1].any() - row[column_2].any(),0)

data['result']=np.nan
for i in range(1,5):
    data['result']=data.apply(test_(data,'a'+str(i),'b'+str(i)))
```

This won't work.

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy`'s `maximum` which applies to the whole column. Then, just iterate over all your numbered columns and append a new column to your dataframe as

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(1,5):
    data['result_' + str(i)] = np.maximum(data['a_' + str(i)] - data['b_' + str(i)], 0)
```

Comment: Could you write a function in case I need to apply to more complicated data?

Comment: Well, in that case depend on what calculation you need to apply

Comment: Yep, but I am wondering how could I apply those above by a function.....

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` columns then using `diff`

```
df=data.groupby(data.columns.str.split('_').str[1].values,axis=1).diff().dropna(1)
df
Out[347]: 
   b_1  b_2  b_3  b_4
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  1.0 -2.0
2  3.0 -5.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0 -7.0  0.0  0.0
4 -2.0  0.0  0.0  2.0
```

Then we using `mask`

```
df.mask(df<0,0)
Out[349]: 
   b_1  b_2  b_3  b_4
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A={'a_1':[1,2,3,4,5],'a_2':[6,7,8,9,4],'a_3':[0,6,2,4,7],'a_4':[3,5,2,4,6],
   'b_1':[1,2,6,4,3],'b_2':[6,7,3,2,4],'b_3':[0,7,2,4,7],'b_4':[3,3,2,4,8]
   }

data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(A)


x = data.iloc[:,0:4].values - data.iloc[:,4:].values
print(x)

x = pd.DataFrame(x)
print(x)
```

output:

```
[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 -1  2]
 [-3  5  0  0]
 [ 0  7  0  0]
 [ 2  0  0 -2]]


   0  1  2  3
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0 -1  2
2 -3  5  0  0
3  0  7  0  0
4  2  0  0 -2
```